# what should be the return of function so get Person object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me  what should be the return of function so that In `both` case I will get `true`

```
function Person(name){
      this.name = name;
      return false;

    }

    var p1 =new Person('ss')
    var p2 = Person('sdd')
    console.log(p1 instanceof Person)
    console.log(p2 instanceof Person)
```

Currently I am getting `true` in first `case` not is `second` so what should i return so the I will get `true` in both cases

IN second case I don't want to use `new` keyword ..why you guys devoted me ..I know using `new` I can create the object.But I want to know how without `new` keyword

Comment: How could it be an `instanceof` if you don't create an instance of it?

Comment: I am saying without using `new`  can I create `person` `object`

Comment: Guys, It no make sense, you voted to close then made answer? If you believe this question is too broad, so should not answer it, if you going to answer, so do not vote to close it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check with [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) and create an instance of the function.

> The `new.target` property lets you detect whether a function or constructor was called using the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator. In constructors and functions instantiated with the new operator, `new.target` returns a reference to the constructor or function. In normal function calls, `new.target` is [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

```js
function Person(name) {
    if (!new.target) {
        return new Person(name);
    }
    this.name = name;
}

var p1 = new Person('ss'),
    p2 = Person('sdd');

console.log(p1 instanceof Person);
console.log(p2 instanceof Person);
```

Comment: this is correct answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to create `p2` as an instance of `Person` as `var p2 = new Person('sdd')` then it will return `true` for `console.log(p2 instanceof Person)`

```js
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
  return false;
}

var p1 =new Person('ss');
var p2 = new Person('sdd');
console.log(p1 instanceof Person);
console.log(p2 instanceof Person);
```

> The instanceof operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes. Also, why is the OP willing to add more code in his function with `if (!new.target)`. At the end of day you are still returning an instance of `Person` so what does it make difference by just using `new` at the time you create a `Person` user5711656?

Comment: he is changing in function body